# SonarQube running as a Windows Service on SQL Server with integrated authentication - Does anyone have a working example?

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, integrated-security

SonarQube is installed as a service.
jtds-1.3.1-dist is used for SQL Server access.
The service works using SQL Server authentication.

I've tried many configurations - a few examples including:

> sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbserver/SonarQube;instance=instance1;SelectMethod=Cursor;integratedSecurity=true
>
> sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbserver/SonarQube;instance=instance1;SelectMethod=Cursor;integratedSecurity=true;domain=thedomain
>
> sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbserver/SonarQube;instance=instance1;SelectMethod=Cursor;integratedSecurity=true;useNtlm2=true;domain=thedomain

while the ntlmauth.dll is scattered around half the folders in the hard drive!

The logs either say things similar to 'user sonar cannot connect' or 'user is from a different domain'.

Nothing seems to work.

I would be grateful if anyone can post a working example of the sonar.jdbc.url and the location of the ntlmaut.dll.

Answer (score 2):

Following setup/configuration of SonarQube and SQL Server with integrated authentication worked for me.

## SonarQube Server

SonarQube Server version =  [5.2](https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.2.zip)

## sonar.properties

sonar.jdbc.url = jdbc:sqlserver://dbserver;databaseName=SonarQube;integratedSecurity=true

### Please note:

1. A database named **SonarQube** must exist and its collation must be **case-sensitive** (CS) and **accent-sensitive** (AS)
   Use the following connection string if you want to use integrated security with Microsoft Sql Server
2. Do not set "**sonar.jdbc.username**" or "**sonar.jdbc.password**" property if you are using "**Integrated Security**".
3. For "**Integrated Security**" to work, you have to download the Microsoft SQL JDBC driver package from
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774
   and copy sqljdbc_auth.dll to a folder and add the folder to environment variable **%PATH%**. Copy the 32 bit or 64 bit version of the dll depending upon the architecture of your SonarQube server machine.
4. This version of SonarQube has been tested with Microsoft SQL JDBC version 4.1 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: At time of writing, the SonarQube version in use was 5.1.2. That is still the case for us, so this answer is unfortunately not relevent.

On our test server with 5.2 it was a simple matter to configure integrated security.